# App is killed when I change orientation of lock screen before unlocking

Tags: android, locking, screen, orientation

I have game running in landscape mode. When I press lock button and then unlock again everything is OK. I also handle screen orientation changes like this:

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

This everything works OK with one exception:

1. I run the game in portrait mode
2. press lock button
3. press unloc button (so I see the lock screen)
4. change orientation to landscape and wait while the lock screen turns
5. swipe lock screen to return to game
6. => app is closed (no error)

   Does anyone know how to handle this? How to prevent or handle screen orientation when lock screen orientation changes just before swiping unlock screen<

Comment: App is closed means, Did you check any exception or error in your log cat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need 'screenSize'. Even though you handle "orientation" changes the screen size changes from X by Y to Y by X and that counts as a screen size change.

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device     
switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime    
restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared 
by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" 
value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must declare  


`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize".`
```

> However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).

Source:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html